# Highlight text(change text background color) in iphone webView

Tags: ios4, iphone

i am looking for highlighting function for so many days and there are no valid answers for it, so i am sorry to post this similar question again. Thanks in advance.

I am loading a word document in iphone webview, and now by default i am able to select/copy and paste the text, i wondering is there a way to highlight the text i selected using my finger and change the background color of that text ?

thanks very much if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible with public API. Non-HTML content is static when displayed in a UIWebView.

Comment: Thanks for ur kindly reply, cause i saw some resources said i can make use of java script in iphone to solve this problem, so do u think is that a possible solution, or maybe u can share with me the correct way to do this highlight stuff? Will be much appreciate if u can help me.

Comment: @user991843 The problem is that when file data is displayed in a UIWebView, the webview will refuse to tell you anything about it. You would be able to manipulate the page with Javascript only if it is HTML. To do so, use UIWebview's stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString method to send Javascript commands and receive their output.

Comment: I get ur point, could u help me with the java script? i have nvr learn about that, thanks very much